# Fetch top N rows of the table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm kind of stuck with a problem that I'm having.
Among others, I have this tables in my DB:

```
Product (int productId, ...otherProductInfo)
Customer (int customerId, ...otherCustomerInfo)
SoldToData ( int productId, int customerId)
```

I want to get top ten selling products using Entity Framework in MVC2. How can I do that?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Following thekip's and Pr0fess0rX's advices, this is what I have done so far, and it seems to be working:

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
    var groupedProducts = (from p in db.Products
                        join s in db.SoldToData
                            on p.productId equals s.productId
                        group p by p.id
                            into ProductGroup
                            orderby ProductGroup.Count() descending
                            select ProductGroup).Take(10).ToList();
     List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
     products.AddRange(groupedProducts.Select(gp => gp.First()));
}
```

Is this the proper way?

Comment: Following thekip's and Pr0fess0rX's advices, this is what I have done so far, and it seems to be working:
`using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
 var groupedProducts = (from p in db.Products
      join s in db.SoldToData
       on p.productId equals s.productId
      group p by p.id
       into ProductGroup
       orderby ProductGroup.Count() descending
       select ProductGroup).Take(10).ToList();
  List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
  products.AddRange(groupedProducts.Select(gp => gp.First()));
}`
Is this the proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an IQueryable to query the datasource you could use orderby etc for ordering followed by Take(10)?

Comment: Hey thekip. Thank you for a quick reply. I haven't used IQueryable yet. I've just gave it a quick look. Can you give me some example?

Comment: How do you get a single row from your database? For example how do you get a product by it's ID?

when using entity framework (or any other ORM) I would certainly use IQueryable for accessing my database.

Comment: `using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {
                var product = (from p in db.Product
where p.productId==id
                           select a).Single();
            }`

Comment: Well assuming you have this, you can join this on SoldToData.

You can group by SoldToData, 

Order by the count,

Take 10 to take the first 10 (top selling) products

Answer (score 1):

1. Join both products and customer
2. Group them and get the count of products per customer
3. Order descending by the count.
4. Take top 10 of the times
5. Get the name of the result products (top 10)